# Can't install plugin and theme

Tags: wordpress, iis, ftp

i want to install some plugin but show

```
Installation failed: Could not create directory.
```

that i find some solution add some code to wp-config

```
//* FTP Settings **/
/** wp-content path */

define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');
define('FTP_BASE', '/');

define('FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/wp-content/');
define('FTP_PLUGIN_DIR', '/wp-content/plugins/');
define('FTP_USER', 'ftpuser');
define('FTP_PASS', 'ftppewd');
define('FTP_HOST', 'domain.com');

define('FTP_SSL', false);

define("FS_METHOD", "direct");
define("FS_CHMOD_DIR", 0777);
define("FS_CHMOD_FILE", 0777);
```

that the error message change to

> Installation failed: Unable to connect to the filesystem. Please
>   confirm your credentials

.
i use IIS 8
use ftp client the ftp account has full access right

Comment: why did you use both ftpext and direct with `FS_METHOD` only one is enough either direct or ftpext? I suggest you to use `define("FS_METHOD", "direct");` remove other constants

Comment: if not add any thing the error show >Installation failed: Unable to locate WordPress content directory (wp-content).

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206022/unable-to-locate-wordpress-content-directory-wp-content

Comment: if add define("FS_METHOD", "direct"); the error is Installation failed: Could not create directory.

Comment: give write permission to `wp-content`

Answer (score 14):

You might also want to check the ownership of the folder: 
try this

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Comment: I believe this is more correct and should be the accepted answer, since most of the cases permission on www is problem.

Answer (score 7):

After a clean install of Wordpress locally, add below statement

`define("FS_METHOD", "direct");`  to my wp-config.php file.

Later change the ownership of the wp-content and the contents inside the wp-content folder to the web server user (_www) I used the below commands.

`sudo chown _www:_www wp-content`

`sudo chown _www:_www wp-content/*`

Alternatively you can also set the permission recursively using

`sudo chown -R _www:_www wp-content/`

Comment: Among other things, adding `define("FS_METHOD", "direct");` and `define("FTP_SSL", false);` fixed my problem!

Comment: running this `sudo chown -R _www:_www [root directory]` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

It complains about FTP credentials when it cannot access the filesystem.

Most likely your permissions are wrong (directory inaccessible by webserver)

If you ensure that your wordpress directory is owned by the same user who runs your webserver, the FTP credentials note should disappear and you should be able to install themes and plugins via Wordpress Admin console.